# could not resolve Model using modelPaths in objectionjs and ts-jest

Tags: node.js, knex.js, ts-jest, objection.js

Getting this error when running ts-jest.

Error: Member.relationMappings.primaryAssignment: modelClass: could not resolve ./MemberAssignment using modelPaths

```
  primaryAssignment: {
        relation: Model.HasOneRelation,
        modelClass: path.join(__dirname, 'MemberAssignment'),
        join: {
          from: 'members.primary_member_assignment_id',
          to: 'member_assignments.id',
        },
      },
```

Works perfectly fine when using tsc

Comment: Looks likes its resolving correctly when added .ts at the end
 modelClass: path.join(__dirname, 'MemberAssignment.ts'),

Comment: Any suggestion how to not do it without .ts?